# Where does Xrandr/Linux keep display state?

Tags: display, cinnamon, xrandr

I have a laptop running Fedora, with Cinnamon as a desktop environment, on Xorg. The laptop has a high-res internal monitor, and an external monitor. Yesterday, i had it set up fine - laptop monitor to the left, primary, with fractional scaling set to 200% to make things look bigger, external monitor to the right; both monitors aligned along the bottom edge. While messing around diagnosing another problem, i managed to get this screwed up somehow (i think i used xrandr to disable the external monitor with `--off`, then turn it on again with `--auto`). I opened the display control panel, and put it back how i wanted. Except ... the external monitor now panned up and down inside a larger framebuffer! And i couldn't summon the auto-hiding bottom panel on the laptop monitor.

I moved the monitors around in the displays control panel, to align them along the top edge. This worked fine - no panning, panel appears. But if i moved the laptop monitor to align on the bottom edge again, the panning behaviour came back. I made no other changes in the display control panel.

Rebooting the machine didn't fix this.

After much investigation, i noticed that in xrandr output, in the broken configuration, the framebuffer was taller than it was in the working configuration. I used xrandr to change the framebuffer to the right size, and now it seems fine, as it was before i started messing around this morning.

So, the problem is that at some point, some part of the graphics stack got the wrong framebuffer size, and then that was hanging around when it didn't make sense.

I am positive that the displays were set up exactly the same way in the control panel as they were before. I went and looked at the cinnamon-monitors.xml file, and it seemed fine. There was no sign of this over-large frambuffer.

So, where was this framebuffer size persisted? Not in cinnamon-monitors.xml. Not in my Xorg configuration, which i didn't edit. So where?

Comment: Hi!
You could try to create scripts as described here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/xrandr#Scripts --> Should work the same with fedora. 
Cheers

Comment: @joshii_h This doesn't relate to my question, about where xrandr stores state, at all.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this thread: https://groups.google.com/g/linux.debian.user/c/dXZDiOs8fxc

It seems most likely is under a file named Xorg.0.log or somewhere in the /sys /proc folders.

Comment: Interesting thread, but that's not what that thread says. In this user's case, the user was running in a virtual machine, managed by VirtualBox, and VirtualBox was persisting the screen size. I am not using a virtual machine. Xorg.0.log is simply a log file, and /sys and /proc are interfaces to the kernel - they cannot store persistent state.

Still, i will definitely have a look in that log file.

Comment: right! Just thought it was a starting point to search. Hope it helps